# How do I add a specific domain/site as an Exception in Firefox Tracking? It's greyed out

Tags: security, exception, firefox, tracking

In Firefox, enter Options > Privacy & Security > under "Enhanced Tracking Protection" click "Manage Exceptions"

There seems to be no way to add a domain or site to the list of excepted sites (currently the list appears to be empty).

I want to exclude a specific domain from having Tracking blocked (Google reCaptcha is not working and I think this is why). I don't want to just blindly allow all tracking, I want to only allow per site for better security.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it. In the Firefox address bar click on the Shield icon left of the URL, then click the Toggle for "Enhanced Tracking Protection is ON for this site":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the site immediately you are trying to unblock redirects to a different site when it detects cookies are blocked, it's very difficult to create an exception. (since you can't stay on that site)  In this case, just turn off cookie blocking altogether temporarily so you can visit the first site.  Then you can create the exception and turn cookie blocking back on.